# ansible with_items when jinja2 templating delimiters

Tags: ansible

The task is to generate passwords if they are not defined in vars. It works in ansible < 2.3, but now I see warnings.

Task:

```
    - debug: var={{item}}
  when: 
    - "{{item}} is not defined"
  with_items:
    - XXX_PASSWORD
    - YYY_PASSWORD
```

Result:

```
    TASK [bootstrap : debug] ****************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.
Found: {{item}} is not defined

ok: [example.com] => (item=XXX_PASSWORD) => {
    "XXX_PASSWORD": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "item": "XXX_PASSWORD"
}
ok: [example.com] => (item=YYY_PASSWORD) => {
    "YYY_PASSWORD": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!",
    "item": "YYY_PASSWORD"
}
```

the problem is that when I remove "{{}}" from when statement it stops working, looks like vars in with_items are always defined.

how should I avoid this warning and keep task working?

answer: 
this code is answering my question:

```
- set_fact:
    XXX_PASSWORD: "{% if XXX_PASSWORD | default('') == '' %}{{ lookup('pipe','openssl rand -hex 16') }}{% else %}{{ XXX_PASSWORD }}{% endif %}"
    YYY_PASSWORD: "{% if YYY_PASSWORD | default('') == '' %}{{ lookup('pipe','openssl rand -hex 16') }}{% else %}{{ YYY_PASSWORD }}{% endif %}"
    ZZZ_PASSWORD: "{% if ZZZ_PASSWORD | default('') == '' %}{{ lookup('pipe','openssl rand -hex 16') }}{% else %}{{ ZZZ_PASSWORD }}{% endif %}"
    ...
    and so on...
```

seems that "with_items" can't be used in my case with ansible >= 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [default](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#default) filter?

```
set_fact:
  XXX_PASSWORD: "{{ XXX_PASSWORD | default('change_me' | shuffle | join) }}"
```

This will leave `XXX_PASSWORD` as is if it is set at the time of `set_fact` execution, or generate new password if `XXX_PASSWORD` is undefined.

Comment: But what if I need to run `local_action: shell openssl rand -hex 16`  if passwords are undefined

Comment: You can use anything you want inside `default`: `default(lookup("pipe","openssl rand -hex 16"))`

Comment: looks good, but is it possible to use with_items with this? 
`- set_fact:
    "{{ item }}": "{{ item | default(lookup('pipe','openssl rand -hex 16')) }}"
  with_items:
    - "XXX_PASSWORD"
    - "YYY_PASSWORD"
`
this code is not working, because ansible assigns openssl command output to the value of XXX_PASSWORD, not to the XXX_PASSWORD variable.